# Can i customize CCAVENUE Alert SMS?

Tags: wordpress, ccavenue

I am currently using CCAVENUE payment gateway for my website. For CCAVENUE account, i enabled alert SMS functionality and provide my mobile number for receiving SMS. I am able to receive the SMS correctly, but we need to customize that SMS text. How can i do that?

Comment: which plugin you are using for this? please share a downloadable link.